# uitableviewcontroller swipe to delete in ios - custom swipe feature

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building a UITableViewController based note taking app. Currently, I am using canEditRowAtIndexPath and commitEditingStyle -> editingStyle Delete to have a swipe and tap to delete feature, for each note/cell.

I would like to change this so instead of just the default red Delete box showing up after a row swipe, I have two icons appear, similar to what happens when someone swipes a note on the iPhone in Evernote.

The icons would be a trash can for deleting the note/cell and another icon/button that is an outlet to a feature of the app.

Any instruction or suggestions on how to implement this feature would be a great help.

[gif of feature in Evernote](http://ericmseitz.com/images/EVSwipe.gif)

Answer (score 0):

you should check out this UITableViewCell subclass: https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

Comment: Thank you Bart. This would certainly do it for me, but I am hesitant to even start to try to implement such a library. I want to build the feature on my own. Now looking at these tutorials. We'll see how far I am able to get through them.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views and http://timbroder.com/2014/08/uitableviewcell-action-swiping-in-ios8-and-swift.html. Either way, I am over my head, but learning :]